# Insert a line after a block of text with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have text file: `file.conf`

```
### Option: LogFile
#       Name of log file.
#       If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=

### Option: LogFileSize
#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1
```

I want to search for a line containing `LogFile`, skip subsequent non-blank lines, and insert a new line with predefined content just before the next blank line.

And I have tried:

```
sed --posix -e '/\bLogFile\b/{:a;n;/^ *$/!ba;i\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log' -e '}' file.conf
```

And this is working fine, for those option blocks which are followed by a blank line. However, it is also possible that the file ends with no blank line, in which case I want to insert the new line at the end of the file. In this example, it would happen if I was looking for `LogFileSize` instead of `LogFile`.

How can I handle this case?

Comment: What `sed` are you using? The given command does nothing. What should the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

A simple possibility would be to

```
echo >>file.conf
```

after `sed` execute I'm not sure it's possible with pure `sed`

Answer (score 0):

You're running inte issues because you're using `i` ("insert") rather than `a` ("append").  `i` insert before a selected line while `a` appends after.

You are also matching the block by the `Option: LogFile` header rather than the more appropriately placed line with the default value (`# LogFile=`).

---

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^# LogFile=/a\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log' file.conf
### Option: LogFile
#       Name of log file.
#       If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=
LogFile=/tmp/log1.log

### Option: LogFileSize
#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1
```

This works with `LogFileSize` as well:

```
$ sed '/^# LogFileSize=/a\LogFileSize=512' file.conf
### Option: LogFile
#       Name of log file.
#       If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=

### Option: LogFileSize
#       Maximum size of log file in MB.
#       0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1
LogFileSize=512
```

Both in one go:

```
$ sed -e '/^# LogFileSize=/a\LogFileSize=512' -e '/^# LogFile=/a\LogFile=/tmp/log1.log' file.conf
```